# Menu não desaparece ao ser clicado em site responsivo bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, layout-responsivo, nav-bar

Estou tentando fazer com que o menu responsivo para celular em um site em bootstrap desapareça por completo ao dar um clique nos links dele. O site é one page e os links funcionam através de Âncoras. O site foi modificado em um tema pronto do themeforest por outra pessoa. Acredito que tenha que ser modificado a classe - nav bar toogle collapse - do bootstrap. Tentei procurar os erros nos arquivos JS porém não encontrei. Segue o link do tema para testar responsivamente o codigo e os prints como exemplo. Agradeço a quem solucionar o problema, fico no aguardo. Tema builder: http://themeforest.net/item/builder-responsive-construction-site-template/full_screen_preview/11062294

[Menu à ser modificado](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tjq2F.png)
[image: Tema original][image: Como deverá ficar o menu][image: tema original]

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-BR">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 <meta name="description" content=".">
 <meta name="keywords".">
    <meta name="author" content="https://plus.google.com/103758766556143989736" />
    <link rel="publisher" href="https://plus.google.com/103758766556143989736" />
    <link rel="canonical" href="" />
    <meta name="robots" content="index, follow" />
    <meta name="Googlebot" content="all" />
    <link rel="icon" href="favicon.png" type="image/png">
    <title></title>
    <!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/owl-carousel.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=PT+Sans:400,400italic,700,700italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,300,400italic,300italic,600,600italic,700,700italic,800,800italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link href="css/custom.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- SLIDER REVOLUTION 4.x CSS SETTINGS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/extralayers.css" media="screen" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="rs-plugin/css/settings.css" media="screen" />
    <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
</head>
<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <section id="topbar" class="clearfix">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
                        <p class="center"><i class="fa fa-phone"></i>(11)2887-9388 / (11)97567-7657</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
                        <p class="center"><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i>Atendimento - Horário Comercial </p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
                        <p class="center"><i class="fa fa-envelope-o"></i></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- end row -->
            </div>
            <!-- end container -->
        </section>
        <!-- end section -->
        <header class="header clearfix">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <nav id="jtheader" class="navbar navbar-default">
                    <div class="navbar-header">
                        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
                            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        </button>
                        <a class="navbar-brand" href="">
                            <img src="png" alt="logo">
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                            <li><a href="#sobre-nos">Sobre nós</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#servicos">Serviços</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#clientes">Clientes</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#contato">Contato</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <!--/.nav-collapse -->
                </nav>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Basta adicionar esse javascript na página que ao clicar no menu ele fechara

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $(".navbar-nav li a").click(function(event) {
    $(".navbar-collapse").collapse('hide');
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Bom, se o seu código todo é esse, é porque falta a parte final da página... as tags e classes estão todas corretas, fiz o teste aqui, só precisei adicionar a parte final e modificar os links dos estilos, para pegar de algum CDN. Também testei pegando do próprio site do tema, e funcionou também. Abaixo a parte que adicionei:

```
<!--/.container-fluid -->
    </header><!-- end header -->

    <section>
    <h1>Vai Corinthians</h1>
    <p>Ganhamos mais uma</p>
    </section>

    <div class="dmtop">Scroll to Top</div>

</div><!-- /#wrapper -->

<!-- jQuery -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<!--<script src="js/custom.js"></script>-->

</body>
</html>
```

ps: A section final adicionei para testar, e o HTML restante foi do fonte do tema, só alterando os links para usar os CDNs.

Se você puder, remova as sections da sua página temporariamente para verificar as tags finais e os javascripts, especialmente o jquery e o do bootstrap, são eles que dão a funcionalidade ao menu. Veja se a página consegue encontrar o caminho deles.

Comment: nossa, agora que vi que a pergunta é de 2015... mas ela apareceu na página inicial :P